# how to count specific coumns row data in mysql without any conditons in php pdo?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have table "POST_DATA" and consists of total (13) fields. like userID, user_name,pass, cam_name,cam_model etc..  whenever a user registers on my website some fields get updated like (userid,user_name,pass) and other fields are empty.
But the problem is when I retrieve data from another PHP file using rowcount() on specific columns it returns "1" every time, I want to "0" if no data found on that specific fields like(cam_img,cam_name,cam_model etc..) still it not get updated.
what is the problem...

here is my code:

```
$stmt = $index_home->getDetails();


if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
{

    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        extract($row);
        ?>      
  <div class="row">         
      <div class="span9" style="float:right;">

        <ul class="thumbnails list row" style="display:block;" >
             <li>
                  <div class="thumbnail">
                      <div class="row">
                       <div class="span3"> <span class="sale tooltip-test"> <i class="icon-gift font24"></i> <br>
                       New</span> <a href="#"><img alt=""  src="user_images/<?php echo $row['cam_img']; ?>"></a>   
                       </div>

                       <div class="span6"> <span class="prdocutname" style="font-size:20px;" ><?php echo  ucfirst($cam_name) ." " .$cam_model?></span></div>

                       <div class="span6"> <span class="prdocutname" ><?php echo "Rent: " . $cam_rent . "/- (per day)"?></span></div>
                       <div class="span6"> <span class="prdocutname" ><?php echo "Mobile: " . $mobile ?></span></div>
                       <div class="span6">
                        <button  data-original-title="Cart" class="btn btn-orange tooltip-test"> <i class="icon-shopping-cart icon-white"></i> </button>
                        <button  data-original-title="Wishlist" class="btn btn-orange btn-small tooltip-test"> <i class="icon-heart icon-white"></i> </button>
                        <button  data-original-title="Compare" class="btn btn-orange btn-small tooltip-test"> <i class="icon-refresh icon-white"></i> </button>
                       </div>


                       <a href="#" onclick="window.open('view_item.php?id=<?php echo $row['userID']; ?>')" class="btn btn-orange btn-small  addtocartbutton">Detail view</a> </div>

                       </div>
                    </div>
              </li>      
         </ul> 
       </div>
     <?php
    }
}
else
{
    ?>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="alert alert-warning">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> &nbsp; No Data Found ...
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}   
?>
```

And getDetails() implementation in USER class

```
public function getDetails()
{
    try
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT userID, user_name, cam_name, cam_model, cam_rent, cam_img, mobile FROM post_data ORDER BY userID DESC');
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt;
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex)
    {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
    }
}
```

I want to restrict rowCount() to return "1" if no data found in that particular columns.

Comment: rowCount is like its named - count rows, not columns (columns, are fields based on your text ;) ). If you want to check if field is empty, you have to check value, like $row['cam_img']

Comment: provide me some code snippet for checking particluar columns row data ..

Comment: just after your extract put some if condition where you check your field if($cam_rent){ die('field is not empty'); }